# Why is my JS dynamic headline text not updating in real time?

Tags: javascript

Hey everyone I'm experimenting with some cool text effects, but for some reason when I run the code it doesn't create the effect. The effect being to dynamically change the text when someone lands on the page. I've included the code snippet below to help out. Your help is much appreciated!

```html
<span id="typed"></span>
<span class="typed-cursor" style="animation-iteration-count: 0;">

JS (this.cursor=document.createElement("span"),this.cursor.className="typed-cursor"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create and append a span element in the body section like that?

```js
this.cursor=document.createElement("span");
this.cursor.className="typed-cursor";
this.cursor.innerText="typed-cursor";
document.body.appendChild(this.cursor)
```

```html
<span id="typed"></span>
<span class="typed-cursor" style="animation-iteration-count: 0;"></span>
```